# How to pass Firebase JSON to app with code

Tags: android, json, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I wonder if there is any way in that I can import a firebase database JSON to the app via code and then access it via code from the app (Kotlin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native Android API for Firebase doesn't take JSON as its input or output. But the REST API does, so you could access the REST API in your app to work directly with JSON. Alternatively you could write a (fairly simple) wrapper to do the conversion from `DataSnapshot`s to the corresponding JSON.